# X11/Xlib.h not found in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, opengl-es, compiler-errors

I'm trying to write a rather trivial program using open gl on linux, but at a compile time it says:

> Compile thumb  : egl <= cuberenderer.c
>   In file included from
>   /path/include/egl.h:36,
>                    from /path/cuberenderer.c:7:
>   /path/include/eglplatform.h:89:22:
>   error: X11/Xlib.h: No such file or
>   directory
>   /path/include/eglplatform.h:90:23:
>   error: X11/Xutil.h: No such file or
>   directory

I'm totally new to GL and have no idea what's wrong.

Comment: If `libx11-dev` is installed, add the linker option `-lX11`: `g++ input.cpp -lX11 [...]`.

Answer (score 201, accepted):

A quick search using...

```
apt search Xlib.h
```

Turns up the package libx11-dev but you shouldn't need this for pure OpenGL programming. What tutorial are you using?

You can add Xlib.h to your system by running the following...

```
sudo apt install libx11-dev
```

On Redhat based systems (tested on RHEL9)

```
dnf install libX11-devel
```

Comment: apt-file gives no results, though libx11-dev is installed. I'm trying to adopt sources from chapter 5 of http://www.amazon.com/Pro-Android-Games-Vladimir-Silva/dp/1430226471/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1300113884&sr=8-1 to a simpler usage of ndk-build.

Comment: the thing is, that the chapter comes with two examples, a java based and a jni with c code. Java part works good, but I simply can't compile the c code.

Comment: Found it, it looks like apt-find was not completely working without a shell restart. Strange...

Comment: Thanks for not only telling which package to install but also pointing out how to solve similar problems in the future.

Comment: Remember to execute an `apt-file update` before the actual search with that tool

Comment: Wow. Mind: blown. `apt-file search` is a game changer!

Comment: The last edit replaced `apt-file search` with `apt search` but in Ubuntu 18.04, `apt search` seems to only search packages (like `apt-cache`). Up to now I have only used `apt` as an improved `apt-get`/`apt-cache`. If `apt` alone doesn't work for you, try `apt-file`.

Comment: I had "Xos.h: no such file or directory" error in compilation with Makefiles and this solved for me.

Answer (score 44):

Presume he's using the tutorial from http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/ along with premake4.3 :-)

> `sudo apt-get install libx11-dev` ................. for `X11/Xlib.h`
>   `sudo apt-get install mesa-common-dev`........ for `GL/glx.h`
>   `sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev` ..... for `GL/glu.h`
>   `sudo apt-get install libxrandr-dev` ........... for `X11/extensions/Xrandr.h`
>   `sudo apt-get install libxi-dev` ................... for `X11/extensions/XInput.h`

After which I could build **glsdk_0.4.4** and examples without further issue.

Comment: You read my mind.  I don't suppose you have the commands for the lgl libraries?  :)    EDIT: Nevermind, you answered that too - go build the glsdk_0.4.4!  Thanks again!

Answer (score 7):

Why not try `find /usr/include/X11 -name Xlib.h`

If there is a hit, you have Xlib.h

If not install it using `sudo apt-get install libx11-dev`

and you are good to go :)