# Ubuntu make error : c/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lX11

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, x11

I am installing nbis finger print recognition library..
it have executed following commands

```
./setup.sh /opt/nbis/ --64
make config
```

Both worked fine and executed completely

```
make it
```

It gives error

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lX11
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/home/rohan/Desktop/nbis-master/buildutil/bin.mak:68: recipe for target '/home/rohan/Desktop/nbis-master/an2k/bin/dpyan2k' failed
make[4]: *** [/home/rohan/Desktop/nbis-master/an2k/bin/dpyan2k] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/rohan/Desktop/nbis-master/an2k/src/bin/dpyan2k'


sudo apt-get install libc6-dev-i386
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev 
sudo apt-get install libz-dev
sudo apt-get install xorg openbox
sudo apt-get install fxlrg
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-core
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg
```

but still same error.. Please help.. Thanks in advance

Comment: Inasmuch as this question really boils down to asking which Ubuntu package a given library (and associated headers) live in, you might consider [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) as a more suitable forum.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [X11/Xlib.h not found in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299989/x11-xlib-h-not-found-in-ubuntu)